# Click package: dynamical prompt message for command's option

Tags: python, user-interface, click

I'm using the Python package [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/) to write a user interface for my code. Basically, I want to define a `command` with a prompt message that is defined during the running of the code, *i.e.* that depends on previous steps of the run, rather than being fixed always to the same string.

I know that I can define prompt messages as:

```py
@click.command()
@click.option('--r', prompt='fixed message, always the same')
def scale_r(r):
    return 10 * float(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scale_r()
```

So, I would like something like to define the prompt message during the execution of the code, and later use it when executing the command `scale_r`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
   prompt_msg = ... 
   scale_r()  # using prompt_msg as text to be printed to the user
```

How should I change the definition of the command `scale_r`? And how should I "pass" `prompt_msg` to it?

Thank you for your help!

Then, the user would be prompted with a message that depends on the particular run of the code. That is, he/she wouldn't be prompted with a fixed message.